# I don't know how to do OnClick event to change colors of a square

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a totaly beginner at this stuff, so I would be grateful if someone could help me with that. I know for most of you it's a really simple code but for me it's like super hard xD

Ok so my HTML is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Div, class, id </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jFunc.js"></script>





</head>
<body> 

    <div id="Blue" class="yellow"></div>
    <div id="Red" class="Green"></div>
</body>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
body {
color: #a280e2;
font: 1.2em/1.4em 'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif,;
text-align: left;
margin: 0px;
}


.yellow {
background: yellow;
 margin: 100 auto;
padding: 20px; 
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

.green {
background: green;
margin: 100 auto;
padding: 20px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

#Blue {
background: #2700ff;
margin: 100 auto;
padding: 20px; 
width: 100px;
height: 100px; 
}

#Red {
background: #ff0000;
margin: 100 auto;
padding: 20px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Also tried this javascript :

```
$(".yellow").on("click", function () {
$(this).toggleClass(".yellow");});
```

So basicly i want the blue square to change to color yellow when i click on it, and when i click on red it should turn to green. If possible whenever you do a on click demand a pop up alert would come up saying the colors have changed.

Thank you for all your help in advance :)

Comment: Did you tried any javascript code?

Comment: Tried this but i have next to no idea how this works, just started to learn it. 
$(".yellow").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass(".yellow");
});

Comment: Add this into the post. It becomes easier for us to find the issue.

Comment: This is a basics of jQuery. You should start [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/). [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/),

Comment: @Lauromine , There's a `jQuery` tag and the jQuery code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toggleClass()` will do the trick. Check working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/L55qbp1j/1/

Comment: Answers should contain all the necessary information in the answer body itself.  Your answer is hidden behind a link. Please include the relevant portion of your link inside the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an EventListener to your divs :

JS:

```
var myFirstDiv = document.querySelector('#Blue'); //Gets the divs with their ids
var mySecondDiv = document.querySelector('#Red');

myFirstDiv.addEventListener('click', function() { //Registers the EventListeners
   //The code here is executed when you click on myFirstDiv(= #Blue)
    myFirstDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    alert('First Div changed!');
}

mySecondDiv.addEventListener('click', function() {
    mySecondDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    alert('Second Div changed!');
}
```

JS (with jQuery) :

```
var myFirstDiv = $('#Blue');
var mySecondDiv = $('#Red');

myFirstDiv.on('click', function() { //Registers the EventListeners
   //The code here is executed when you click on myFirstDiv(= #Blue)
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: 'yellow'});
    alert('First Div changed!');
}

mySecondDiv.on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({backgroundColor: 'green'});
    alert('Second Div changed!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below java script snippet it will do the trick

---

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
$( "#Blue" ).click(function() {
$('#Blue').css('background-color', 'yellow');
alert( "Color Changed" );
});
$( "#Red" ).click(function() {
$('#Red').css('background-color', 'green');
alert( "Color Changed" );
});
});

</script>
```

---

Here is the complete html file you can use for demo.

---

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title> Div, class, id </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css"/>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<style>
body {
color: #a280e2;
font: 1.2em/1.4em 'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif,;
text-align: left;
margin: 0px;
}


.yellow {
background: yellow;
margin: 100 auto;
padding: 20px; 
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

.green {
background: green;
margin: 100 auto;
padding: 20px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

#Blue {
background: #2700ff;
margin: 100 auto;
padding: 20px; 
width: 100px;
height: 100px; 
}

#Red {
background: #ff0000;
margin: 100 auto;
padding: 20px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
</style>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
$( "#Blue" ).click(function() {
$('#Blue').css('background-color', 'yellow');
alert( "Color Changed" );
});
$( "#Red" ).click(function() {
$('#Red').css('background-color', 'green');
alert( "Color Changed" );
});
});

</script>


</head>
<body> 

    <div id="Blue" class="yellow"></div>
    <div id="Red" class="Green"></div>
</body>
</html>
```